# One Large Table or Multiple Tables?

Tags: php, database, database-design, datatable

I am trying to build a website that has a similar design to the way Facebook groups work. Users will be able to join groups and then post within those groups. However, I am having trouble creating the database schema in regard to groups and posts. This is my table schema thus far:

```
Table 1: Users
Table 2: Groups
Table 3: Posts
```

The posts table will create a row every-time a user posts within a group. That row within the post table will have the unique ID of the group that post is for as well as the unique ID of the user who created the post. My worry is that the post table will become massive, especially massive in comparison to the Groups and Users tables.

considering that there will be many posts (hundreds to thousands) per group, should I create a new table for every group?

Any and all input on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if a user can be a member of more than one group, you need a User_group table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in simplistic view, if there is a dependency of any kind between data items then a new table should be created. You can look it up more precisely here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first_normal_form

It does not state though that a new table should be created every time the table becomes too large. That would be something for a database administrator. In your example, the most recent posts will be read more often than those written 5 months ago. For the sake of proper indexing and to avoid duplicates in data rows, you could use a structure like this:

[image]

*Note) This diagrams says that; i) one user will post to one or more groups, ii) one group will have one or more users, iii) one post will be viewed by one or more users in a group. All 3 relations are one-to-many and the cardinality between users and group is many-to-many.*

Moreover, you could "group/structure" your posts, - the table that is likely to grow over time - into years, months or even weeks. So then you would be able to say for which time period, whereby you could also make this time factor a date field in your posts table instead of a separate table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a word, NO. You should NOT create multiple tables.  One groups table is appropriate.  Index it appropriately it should be fine.  Hundreds or thousands of posts is practically nothing to a database, which is designed to be able to manage millions of rows with proper indexing.  A column of your table should identify the group ownership, but you should not split it into different tables.

In the very worst case, you could partition your table when it became unmanageably large to fit in your disk space.  However, the likelihood of it growing that large is incredibly small.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're into tens of millions of posts, or posts are likely to be very large, or you have very limited hardware, you should be fine with a single MySQL table, as long as you have an index on the group ID.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we are speaking of million+ of rows you will be perfectly fine, as long as you index the table correctly (index by both IDs).